# Вывести в отдельный массив все строки, состоящие из двух слов

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно вывести в отдельный массив всех животных, чьи названия состоят из 2х слов.

```
$animals = array(
    "Africa" => array('Elephants','Gorilla'),
    "Australia" => array('Kangaroo','Koala bear'),
    "South America" => array('Panthera onca','Anaconda'),
    "North America" => array('Haliaeetus leucocephalus','Gray Wolf'),
    "Asia" => array('Ailuropoda melanoleuca','Bengal Tiger'),
    "Europe" => array('Bos primigenius','Wolverine'),
    "Antarctica" => array('Aptenodytes forsteri','Aptenodytes patagonica'),
);
```

Как это можно сделать? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Пытался методом explode вывести, но не смог, так как пока плохо понимаю как это все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($animals as $countinent) {
    $result = array_merge($result, array_filter($countinent, function ($item){ return count(explode(' ', $item)) === 2; }) );
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Если писать в одну строку то код выглядит круче (нет)

Comment: Если честно, то в PHP в отличие от JS используется вызов функций, а не вызов метода у объекта Array, по этому получается достаточно длинная многословная конструкция, с определенной вложенностью, и я пока не научился оформлять подобные конструкции, чтобы код выглядел "круто".

Comment: Я разобрался, все работает!)